# Problem with BIRT on Linux

Tags: linux, exception, birt

I tried to use BIRT in my webapplication project. But I'm getting this kind of exception all the time:

```
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.FrameworkException: Could not find the Framework - org.eclipse.osgi at 
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.doStartup(OSGILauncher.java:123) at 
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.access$0(OSGILauncher.java:94) at 
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher$1.run(OSGILauncher.java:79) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.startup(OSGILauncher.java:75) at
org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.startup(Platform.java:79) at 
org.apache.jsp.webcontent.test3_jsp._jspService(test3_jsp.java:67) at 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at     
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374) at 
...
```

Anyone an idea, what this can be?

I tried it local at my windows machine - all worked fine, but when I start the report on the linux server, it won't run.

I also tried to set the necessary permissions in the tomcat 50local.policy - giving him all the permissions for the moment - like: permission java.lang.AllPermission;

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the JVM cannot find the framework libraries. Just add an environment variable pointing to the "platform" directory under your BIRT installation. Call this variable "birthome";

So your JVM (Tomcat for example) should get an additional parameter at startup like this:

```
–Dbirthome="C:\PROGRA~1\ACTUAT~1\Jar\BIRT\platform"
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but that looks like you don't have the BIRT runtime correctly deployed on your linux server.

Comment: thx, I think I found the problem. I copied the BIRT runtime directly from the original zip file to my server directories - now it's working. Maybe it was a problem between Windows and Linux files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all the jars in Birt runtime lib are under path.
If your are using tomcat make sure all the jars are under /WEB-INF/lib/